# Jumbled tiles in itemTouchHelperCallback in StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I am using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` in my code.

**Take a look at this first:**

[image: my]

**I am facing these problems:**

> In 1st attempt, I move the tile '1' directly upwards by one step and then stop. Everything looks good and the tile labled as '1' replaces label '2'.

> In 2nd attempt, I drag the tile labeled '3' up but do not stop. Still it automatically gets replaced by '1' which is present just above '3'. Something is trouble here.

> In my 3rd and 4th attempt, I try to drag my tile up & sideways. Once I do it the tile automatically gets right  shifted and out of the frame(even though my touch is still holding it). It can be visible only when I drag it left.  Weird!

Now take a look at my code

**In my MainActivity's onCreateMethod**

```
val layoutmanager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 3 
                                              else 2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
layoutmanager.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutmanager
noteAdapter = NoteAdapter(myList, this)
recyclerView.adapter = noteAdapter
```

**My `ItemTouchHelperCallback` method**

```
private val itemTouchHelperCallback =
            object :
                    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, 0
                    ) {

                override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
                    return true
                }

                override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled(): Boolean {
                    return true
                }

                override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
                    val dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN or
                            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT
                    val swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START or ItemTouchHelper.END
                    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags)
                }

                override fun onMove(
                        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                ): Boolean {
                    val fromPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                    val toPosition = target.adapterPosition

                    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
                        for (i in fromPosition until toPosition) {
                            Collections.swap(myList, i, i + 1)
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (i in fromPosition downTo toPosition + 1) {
                            Collections.swap(myList, i, i - 1)
                        }
                    }
                    noteAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)


                    return false
                }
                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                    
                }

            }
```

**UPDATE**

@Zain found out that the real problem was hidden in my `NoteAdapter.java`, so I am highlighting the faulty method. Check his answer.

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: It will be great if you can provide a demo project on Github where we can easily reproduce the problem, so we don't spend any time on the project setup.

Comment: I already have this project uploaded on github. You can download with this commit: https://github.com/anandarpit/Notify/tree/877b07b8986a0ef67d6358a0748f54da0328a240 Thanks! @HarisDautović

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:**

Returning the item position from [`getItemViewType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemViewType(int)) of the `RecyclerView` adapter; while you only have one item view type.

**Short Answer:**

You shouldn't override `getItemViewType()` to keep it to the default, or you can make it return 0 to indicate that there is a single view type for the adapter.

[image]

**Long Answer:**

When the adapter is first attached to the RecyclerView, The RecyclerView's LayoutManager needs to know the layout type of each item position; and to do that it calls `getItemViewType(position)` for each single position in the adapter; so if the adapter list has 10 items, then it's called 10 times; each time it is called, then it returns the type of this particular item.

When `getItemViewType(position)` is not overriden the returned value for all of the items is 0; which indicates that all the items have the same type.

By logging that while returning 0:

```
2021-01-13 11:05:25.941 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 0 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:25.950 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:25.954 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 1 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:25.959 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 1
2021-01-13 11:05:25.962 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 2 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:25.970 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 2
2021-01-13 11:05:25.974 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 3 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:25.979 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 3
2021-01-13 11:05:25.982 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 4 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:25.988 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 4
2021-01-13 11:05:26.000 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 0 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:26.001 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 1 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:26.001 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 2 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:26.001 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 3 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:05:26.001 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 4 Return: 0
```

But as you instead return `position` from `getItemViewType(position)`; then you have as many types of items as the number of positions you have (i.e. the size of the list).

The log in this case:

```
2021-01-13 11:11:30.123 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 0 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:11:30.145 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 0
2021-01-13 11:11:30.149 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 1 Return: 1
2021-01-13 11:11:30.160 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 1
2021-01-13 11:11:30.164 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 2 Return: 2
2021-01-13 11:11:30.172 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 2
2021-01-13 11:11:30.175 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 3 Return: 3
2021-01-13 11:11:30.179 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 3
2021-01-13 11:11:30.183 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 4 Return: 4
2021-01-13 11:11:30.190 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 4
2021-01-13 11:11:30.199 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 0 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:11:30.199 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 1 Return: 1
2021-01-13 11:11:30.200 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 2 Return: 2
2021-01-13 11:11:30.200 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 3 Return: 3
2021-01-13 11:11:30.200 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 4 Return: 4
```

Now the `RecyclerView` is in the steady state (i.e. populated with all the items), and we are going to drag one item and drop it on another.

**Now we'll Replace Note no.1 with 3 (i.e. replacing position 4 with position 2 in the adapter)**

The log when  `getItemViewType()` returns 0

```
2021-01-13 11:14:26.620 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 0 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:14:26.620 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 1 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:14:26.620 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 2 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:14:26.621 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 3 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:14:26.621 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 4 Return: 0
```

Here the `getItemViewType` is called only once for each position and that is because you have only a single view type. And there is no calls to `onBindViewHolder` as we just called `notifyItemMoved` so that the `RecyclerView` only calls gets cached/recycled versions as all the view types are the same in this case.

The log when  `getItemViewType()` returns `position`

```
2021-01-13 11:12:13.659 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 0 Return: 0
2021-01-13 11:12:13.660 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 1 Return: 1
2021-01-13 11:12:13.660 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 2 Return: 2
2021-01-13 11:12:13.660 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 2 Return: 2
2021-01-13 11:12:13.665 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 2
2021-01-13 11:12:13.667 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 3 Return: 3
2021-01-13 11:12:13.668 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 3 Return: 3
2021-01-13 11:12:13.673 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 3
2021-01-13 11:12:13.675 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 4 Return: 4
2021-01-13 11:12:13.675 : getItemViewType:  Pos = 4 Return: 4
2021-01-13 11:12:13.681 : onBindViewHolder: Pos: 4
```

Here the `getItemViewType` is called multiple times as each item has its unique view type, and it needs to recalculate that View type, and also redraw (or recalculate the layout) of the item using `onBindViewHolder` for the `from` (item 2) & `to` (item 4) items and the items in-between (item 3).

Making these multiple view types make you unable to complete the Drag (probably due to new layout recalculation), and also let the intermediate Views unable to shift between the dragged and dropped-on items.

Comment: Well thankyou so much for going to this extent and finding out the error. Few people do that. I will update my question with the faulty portion of my NoteAdapter. Just Great!!!